# how can i get forward email button in html email newsletter?

Tags: html, html-email, php

I'm sending a  HTML newsletter for my site using php and HTML.  In my HTML newsletter i want to add forward email link. how can i do that?

Comment: There's no such thing as a "forward email link".  Forwarding an email is something done as part of the email browser application - you get that for free when people read the email.  It is not part of standard html/javascript/php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A link in an email can only open a new browser tab. you can add a new page on your site that contains this functionality and link this page in your email.